# Extracting a block out of a multidimensional matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

Consider the multi-dimensional matrix `A` where `size(A)` has the identical even elements `N`. How should one find the matrix `B` with `size(B)=size(A)/2` such that:

```
B(1,1,...,1)=A(1,1,...,1),
B(1,1,...,2)=A(1,1,...,2),
...
B(N/2,N/2,...,N/2)=A(N/2,N/2,...,N/2).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally don't like `arrayfun` (or loopy functions), but if the number of dimensions is not in the thousands, then this should be just fine:

```
Nv = size(A)/2;
S = arrayfun(@(x){1:x},Nv);
B = A(S{:});
```

Should work with different sized dimensions too.  Just decide how you want to deal with dimensions where `mod(size(A),2)~=0`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I supposed N is even as mentioned above.

Comment: For a solution without loops use `S=repmat({1:size(A,1)/2},ndims(A),1)`

Comment: Just realized there aren't thousands of dimensions. There are at most 47 (or maybe 64 in recent versions) non-singleton dimensions. Anything beyond can't be indexed and would require indices larger than uint64. Optimizing here is totally unnecessary, iterating such few values arrayfun is totally fine.

Comment: @Daniel I figured it was something like that.  Thanks for the info.